# MySQL sum values diagonally

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, recursive-query, metabase

I have a table which looks like this:

```
| created_at | Current_Value | M1  | M2  | M3  | M4  |
| ---------- | ------------- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/08/2020 | 840           | 840 | 838 | 838 | 838 |
| 01/09/2020 | 65            | 63  | 61  | 59  | 0   |
| 01/10/2020 | 109           | 104 | 99  | 0   | 0   |
| 01/11/2020 | 105           | 100 | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| 01/12/2020 | 61            | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
```

The `Current_Value` columns stores count of items created in the `created_at` month, the columns `M1` - `M4` stores `Current_Value` value minus the decrease of that value in the following months relative to the `created_at` month, so for example columns `M1` in the second row (date 01/09/2020) tells me that in M1 (next month, so 01/10/2020) the value was 63, so it decreased by 2 (65 - 63) and so on.

Now I would like to create an aggregated report in Metabase showing the overall decrease in the number of items per month - meaning ONE total row.

Now the problem is, that because I am creating this report in Metabase I can not use stored routines, nor can I use any other language, so I am stuck just with basic MySQL.

What I need to achieve is to diagonally add the values, so, for example, I need to do this:

**NOTE: the phrase** *previous row* **is abbreviated as** `pr` **so it is more concise**

```
| created_at | Current_Value | M1            | M2            | M3             | M4  |
| ---------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------- | --- |
| 01/08/2020 | 840           | 840           | 838           | 838            | 838 |
| 01/09/2020 | 65 + M1 in pr | 63 + M2 in pr | 61 + M3 in pr | 59 + M4 in pr  | 0   |
| 01/10/2020 | 109+ M1 in pr | 104+ M2 in pr | 99 + M3 in pr | 0              | 0   |
| 01/11/2020 | 105+ M1 in pr | 100+ M2 in pr | 0             | 0              | 0   |
| 01/12/2020 | 61 + M1 in pr | 0             | 0             | 0              | 0   |
```

Now under normal circumstances, I would just use session variables to achieve this, so I would do something like:

```
(@varM1 :=  0  + @varM1) AS M1_Prev, ( @varM1 := M1) M1_Now
```

to get the value from the previous row so I could add it to the current row, however, what I need to do here is not just take the value from the previous row but take already **summed** value from the previous row, so what I actually need to do would look like this:

**NOTE: each cell is stretched to 3 rows, however, it still represents only one cell**

```
| created_at | Current_Value | M1            | M2            | M3             | M4  |
| ---------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------- | --- |
| 01/08/2020 | 840           | 840           | 838           | 838            | 838 |
| ---------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------- | --- |
| 01/09/2020 | 65 + M1 in pr | 63 + M2 in pr | 61 + M3 in pr | 59 + M4 in pr  | 0   |
|            | = 65 + 840    | = 63 + 838    | = 61 + 838    | = 59 + 838     |     |
|            | = 905         | = 901         | = 899         | = 897          |     |
| ---------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------- | --- |
| 01/10/2020 | 109+ M1 in pr | 104+ M2 in pr | 99 + M3 in pr | 0              | 0   |
|            | = 109 + 901   | = 104 + 899   | = 99 + 897    |                |     |
|            | = 1010        | = 1003        | = 996         |                |     |
| ---------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------- | --- |
| 01/11/2020 | 105+ M1 in pr | 100+ M2 in pr | 0             | 0              | 0   |
|            | = 105 + 1003  | = 100 + 996   |               |                |     |
|            | = 1108        | = 1096        |               |                |     |
| ---------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------- | --- |
| 01/12/2020 | 61 + M1 in pr | 0             | 0             | 0              | 0   |
|            | = 61 + 1096   |               |               |                |     |
|            | = 1157        |               |               |                |     |
| ---------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------- | --- |
```

So I need to end up with the same table, but with values aggregated in this way, so I can work with the result.

I have been scratching my head over this problem for the past few hours rearranging and creating new variables to achieve this, but unfortunately, I had no success.

Is this even possible with plain MySQL? Is it is possible, could you please point me in the right direction, because I am unfortunately stuck.

I am using MySQL v5.7.

Thank you very much

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Comment: @Strawberry I know it is kind of clunky, however, there is no other way to do it in Metabase, I know I might have to do it programmatically outside of Metabase and MySQL, but I would like to first know if there is some way to do it in MySQL or if it is not possible, so there is no point in trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data model makes things more difficult than they should. Although this *might* possible with unpivot/pivot and window functions, I find that the logic is simpler to express with a recursive query:

```
with  recursive
    data as (select t.*, row_number() over(order by created_at) rn from mytable t),
    cte as (
        select rn, created_at, current_value, m1, m2, m3, m4 from data where rn = 1
        union all
        select d.rn, d.created_at,
            d.current_value + c.m1, d.m1 + c.m2, d.m2 + c.m3, d.m3 + c.m4, d.m4
        from cte c
        inner join data d on d.rn = c.rn + 1
    )
select * from cte
```

This basically traverses the dataset from the earliest date to the latest, while performing the computation across rows as needed.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cabba92b0c84466ac264fd9c2cd91e81)**:

```
rn | created_at | current_value |   m1 |  m2 |  m3 |  m4
-: | :--------- | ------------: | ---: | --: | --: | --:
 1 | 2020-08-01 |           840 |  840 | 838 | 838 | 838
 2 | 2020-09-01 |           905 |  901 | 899 | 897 |   0
 3 | 2020-10-01 |          1010 | 1003 | 996 |   0 |   0
 4 | 2020-11-01 |          1108 | 1096 |   0 |   0 |   0
 5 | 2020-12-01 |          1157 |    0 |   0 |   0 |   0
```

Note that window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only.

Comment: Thank you very much, tested this on my local DB and it works like a charm, it did not occur to me, that I could use CTE, however as you said in your answer, CTE is available in 8.0, the database I am working on is using MySQL 5.7, so this does not work (I forgot to mention this - I will update my question), is there any other way to achieve this that you are aware of? Thank you

Comment: @Raymond_90: this would be tedious to achieve in MySQL 5.7.

Comment: I thought so, so using Python/R would be the best approach in this situation. I will try to do this using more variables and if I don't succeed I will resort to using Python/R. So there is probably no simple solution to this problem in v5.7 right? Well, that's also an important answer to my question, thank you very much :-)